# Is it possible to use zxing embedded ContinuousCaptureActivity out of the box?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I have the following method in my Activity that is getting called in the `OnCreate` of my `Activity`:

```
public void addListenerOnCameraButton() {
    cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Tracking.this, "Kamera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
        }
    });

    scannerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_scanner);
    scannerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(Tracking.this);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });

    scanContButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_scanner_cont);
    scanContButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Tracking.this, ContinuousCaptureActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

The first two `.setOnClickListener` are not relevant. The third one is. I want to click on my button and have it start the continuous scanning activity.

I was under the assumption that this would work.

I have added `<activity android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.ContinuousCaptureActivity"/>` to my `Manifest` but it does not work.

I receive the error `Unresolved class ContinuousCaptureActivity` both in the `Manifest` as well as in my `Activity`.

Am I wrong in assuming that the `ContinuousCaptureActivity` cannot be used and is more of an example that someone needs to rebuild himself?

Edit: For reference, I used `zxing-embedded` by `journeyapps` which can be found here: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java

I implemented the regular `CaptureActivity` just like this in my `Manifest`:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:replace="screenOrientation" />
```

Comment: How did you include ZXing in your project? What is the package name/contents for `ContinuousCaptureActivity`?

Comment: I added this to the question, I use `zxing-embedded`.

Comment: 1. The activity package name in the manifest should match what you've written - is it `example.zxing.ContinousCaptureActivity` or `com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.ContinuousCaptureActivity` or `com.yourproject.ContinousCaptureActivity` 2. When you included `zxing-embedded` did you use gradle or included the source in your project. Note that the sample project has a ContinousCaptureActivity but the library doesnt.

Comment: I think your last comment is what I'm looking for. I was not certain if this existed or not. I included it via gradle so there will be no `ContinousCaptureActivity` class and I will need to write something similar.